# Flip image onmouseover with php mysql

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, onmouseover

Greatings everyone!

I have some images (100x100) . Depending on the number of results the query returns, I can have numerous images.

On mouse over, every image should flip or just vanish and cames up some text from database. Note that every image has diferent info (text like: description) "on behind".

Im using PHP, Javascript, Jquery, but im not an expert. I've google a bit, but only found flip image1 to image2 , not as I wish.

My big problem is that info i want to show onflip came from a query and java dont work with that.

Can you guide me or show me a tutorial? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a tutorial of something that looks like what you want: http://tutorialzine.com/2010/03/sponsor-wall-flip-jquery-css/

The demo is here: http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/03/sponsor-wall-flip-jquery-css/demo.php

How I work with something new like this is to just write as the tutorial lists it. Next, I get my data and replace the hardcoded values with those from the database.

To get data from a SQL Query into your JavaScript, see: http://nicholaskreidberg.com/2011/using-php-data-in-javascript-functions/

These are the pieces, you just need to put them together. Start by getting the image flip to work with hardcoded values then switch over to getting data from PHP and you are done.

Comment: Beautiful! I hope i could do it on my own :)